# How to use Meteor services in Laravel website

Tags: meteor

I have an application build on **Laravel**.
Purpose of that application is to perform deliveries of goods.
It involves real-time tracking.

On the other hand I am building same application on Angular & Meteor.

Meanwhile I want to store the tracking data in Meteor database (mongodb).

Is there anyway to access Meteor server into my Laravel application to show the real-time tracking?

**UPDATE**

I tried Paulo Mogollón solution but I am facing this error:

```
Loading failed for the module with source file:///E:/Dev/laravelapp/node_modules/isomorphic-ws/index.d.ts
```

[jsfiddle.net/Lrxjed8v](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrxjed8v)

Comment: You want to call meteor from your laravel backend and then display the data on the frontend of meteor app, right?

If so, you can create a rest endpoint on meteor that you can call from laravel, store the data on mongodb and then that will populate you real-time tracking chart or map.

Comment: Actually i want to connect my laravels front end with meteor. I need meteors reactivity on laravel front end

Answer (score 3):

You can connect to your meteor server from anywhere using js with the [simpleddp](https://github.com/Gregivy/simpleddp#readme) package, basically you do this.

```
npm install simpleddp isomorphic-ws --save


import ws from 'isomorphic-ws';
import simpleDDP from 'simpleDDP'; // ES6

const opts = {
    endpoint: "ws://someserver.com/websocket",
    SocketConstructor: ws,
    reconnectInterval: 5000
};
const server = new simpleDDP(opts);


let userSub = server.subscribe("user_pub");
let otherSub = server.subscribe("other_pub", 'param1', 2); // you can specify arguments for subscription

(async ()=>{
    await userSub.ready();
    let nextSub = server.subscribe("next_pub"); // subscribing after sub is ready
    await nextSub.ready();
    //all subs are ready here
})();
```

You can find more examples and information in the package repo. Hope this takes you in the right direction.

Comment: Please check my code in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrxjed8v/ I am getting this error: Loading failed for the module with source “file:///E:/Dev/laravelapp/node_modules/isomorphic-ws/index.d.ts”.

Comment: @StormTrooper, the browser can't run typescript. You need to import the js file for the browser: `import './node_modules/isomorphic-ws/browser.js`

Comment: Now I am getting TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: simpleddp-core

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have installed both modules `npm install simpleddp isomorphic-ws --save`.

Btw do you have `node.js` and `npm` installed? You should also configure you build manager like webpack. Or you can just download minified pre-compiled versions of these libs:

- https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/simpleddp
- https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/isomorphic-ws

Comment: I have them installed, and the paths are also correct.

Comment: Try the pre-compiled versions, just download them and use as ordinary js files.

Comment: You can also check this https://forums.meteor.com/t/new-js-ddp-client-simpleddp/46488/16.